# Why am I getting only "Non-int" outputs despite giving integar inputs?

Tags: python, while-loop

Even after giving integer inputs, I m getting "non-int" as outputs..why?

Code:

```
while True:
  x = input("Enter a number: ")
  if type(x) == int:
    print("int input")
  else:
    print("non-int input")
```

Outputs:

```
Enter a number: 1
non-int input
Enter a number: 2
non-int input
Enter a number: ds
non-int input
Enter a number: fd
non-int input
Enter a number: 4
non-int input
Enter a number: 5
non-int input
```

Comment: because everything is string with `input`. So you get string with one character `"1"`, and not number `1`

Comment: Did you mean: `x = int(input("Enter a number: "))`?

Comment: You should do `try: int(c) except Exception print("non-int")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in Python everything is string with `input`.

So you get string with one character `"1"`, and not number `1`.

You must convert to int explicitly : `int(x)` will be of type `int` if it's actually an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```py
while True:
  try:
    x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print("int input")
  except:
    print("non-int input")
```

The input is a string, use int() to turn into an integer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is there anyway to print "non-int input"?

Answer (score 0):

No while inputting the value it is string. So to check properly you need to put it in try..except to test explicit `int` conversion or use `.isdigit()` like this:

```
while True:
  x = input("Enter a number: ")
  if x.isdigit():
    print("int input")
  else:
    print("non-int input")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, everything coming from input is a string.

Notice, that you should handle a possible exception while parsing:

```py
try:
    _ = int(x)
    print("int input")
except ValueError:
    print("non-int input")
```